# Incorrect Output from loop function (For and While)

Tags: python, loops, math

For my class assignment I am working on code that uses loops utilizing Heron's method to find an estimate of the square root while also displaying the iteration and relative change.

I have the following code:

```
# Problem 1.

def square_root_for(a, x0, max_iter = 10, tol=1e-14):  
    
    """ (number, integer, number) -> float

    Return an estimate of the square root of a number using the Heron's method.
        
    >>> square_root_for(5, 5)
    Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
    -------------------------------------------------
    1         | 3.00000000000000 | 0.4000000000000000
    2         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
    3         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
    4         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
    5         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
    6         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
    7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000
    2.23606797749979
    """
    
    x = [x0]
    x.append(a/x0)
  
    print('Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change')
    print('-------------------------------------------------')
         
    
    for i in range(1,max_iter):
       
        change = (abs(x[i] - x[i-1]) / x[i-1])
        if change > tol:
            x.append(1/2 * (x[i] + (a / x[i])))
        else:
            break
        print('{}         | {:.14f} | {:.16f}'.format(i, x[i], change))
    return(x[i])

        
        
    
           
# Don't change or delete the 5 lines of code below.
a = 5
max_iter = 100
tol = 1e-15
x_final = square_root_for(a, a, max_iter, tol)
print('Final estimate using square_root_for is {0}'.format(x_final))

# Problem 2.

def square_root_while(a, x0, tol=1e-14):
    """ (number, number, number) -> float

    Return an estimate of the square root of a number using the Heron's method.
        
    >>> square_root_while(5, 5)
    Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
    -------------------------------------------------
    1         | 3.00000000000000 | 0.4000000000000000
    2         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
    3         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
    4         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
    5         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
    6         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
    7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000
    2.23606797749979
    """
    
    x = [x0]
    x.append(a/x0)
  
    print('Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change')
    print('-------------------------------------------------')
    
    i = 1
    while i < max_iter + 1:
        change = (abs(x[i] - x[i-1]) / x[i-1])
        if change > tol:
            x.append(1/2 * (x[i] + (a / x[i])))

        else:
            break
        print('{}         | {:.14f} | {:.16f}'.format(i, x[i], change))
        i += 1
        
    return x[i]

        

# Don't change or delete the 4 lines of code below.
a = 5
tol = 1e-15
x_final = square_root_while(a, a, tol)
print('Final estimate using square_root_while is {0}'.format(x_final))
```

The problem is that my output is incorrect. The correct output (As seen in the docstrings) would be:

```
Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
    -------------------------------------------------
    1         | 3.00000000000000 | 0.4000000000000000
    2         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
    3         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
    4         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
    5         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
    6         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
    7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000
    2.23606797749979
```

My output is:

```
Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
    -------------------------------------------------
    1         | 1.00000000000000 | 0.8000000000000000
    2         | 3.00000000000000 | 2.0000000000000000
    3         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
    4         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
    5         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
    6         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
    7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
    2.23606797749979
```

The problem is in the first two lines of outputs, but I can't figure out what I did wrong. Maybe it is something with the math? A student asked my teacher a similar problem and she said "When you do your first append, it's a little different from the other appends re. the math." I'm not sure if that helps. Any tips would be appreciated I am very stuck.

Comment: Which function is causing you problems -  `square_root_for` or  `square_root_while`?

Comment: @JimmyNJ both are having the same problem, but I think if I get help with just one of them maybe I can figure out the other

Comment: you're while loop is not counting over the same range as your `for` it's doing one more but your tolerance test is breaking the loop before you see it. the `range( .. )` function in Python counts up to but not including the `max_iter` value. Your `while` is looping past this.

Comment: What you are printing is the result of the PREVIOUS iteration, not the NEW estimate.  If you change the print statements to print `x[-1]` instead of `x[i]`, then you'll have the same answers.

Comment: Choose a different `x0` (initial guess value for your functions). This value divided by two seems to be the initial guess in the functions.

Comment: @JimmyNJ - That's not the problem. Besides, the comment in the code clearly says "Don't change or delete the  5 lines of code below" i.e., don't change the initial guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following changes to your code:

- the second line in your function should be `x.append(0.5*(x0 + a/x0))`. You need the average of x and a/x (as in every other iteration).
- the `print` statement should be executed before the `if/else` block to print the last line where your relative change falls below the tolerance.

Try:

```
def square_root_for(a, x0, max_iter = 10, tol=1e-14):  
    x = [x0]
    x.append(0.5*(x0 + a/x0))
  
    print('Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change')
    print('-------------------------------------------------')
    
    for i in range(1, max_iter):
        change = (abs(x[i] - x[i-1]) / x[i-1])
        print('{}         | {:.14f} | {:.16f}'.format(i, x[i], change))
        if change > tol:
            x.append(1/2 * (x[i] + (a / x[i])))
        else:
            break
    return(x[i])

>>> square_root_for(5, 5, 100, 1e-15)
Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
-------------------------------------------------
1         | 3.00000000000000 | 0.4000000000000000
2         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
3         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
4         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
5         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
6         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000
Final estimate using square_root_for is 2.23606797749979
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! One more thing though, there should be one more row at the bottom of the output with 7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000, do you know how I could get that to show up?

Comment: I actually can't change the docstring for my assignment, is there another way to do it?

Comment: I haven't changed it at all. I just moved it before the if/else block.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you find yourself guess at what order lines of code should go in, you should try rewriting the code - by now, you should understand what each line means, look at the below:

```
def square_root_for(a, first_guess, max_iter=10, tol=1e-14):
    print('Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change')
    print('-------------------------------------------------')

    # put a and the first guess in a list
    guesses = [a, first_guess]
    # loop for a maximum of max_iter times
    for i in range(1, max_iter):
        # add a new guess to the end of the list
        guesses.append(1 / 2 * (guesses[i] + (a / guesses[i])))
        # compute the relative change between the last guess [-1] and the one before [-2]
        change = abs(guesses[-1] - guesses[-2]) / guesses[-2]
        print('{}         | {:.14f} | {:.16f}'.format(i, guesses[-1], change))
        # stop if the change is at or below tol
        if change <= tol:
            break
    # return the last guess in the list as the result
    return guesses[-1]
```

This returns the same correct result, but note how every line that does something is actually easier to understand, because it more literally describes  itself. You almost don't need the comments.

Comment: Of course,  if the course requires using `x0` as the name of the second parameter, that doesn't change things - I'd probably call your `x` `xs` in that case though.